# Debugging remote WildFly dockerized app in Intellij IDEA

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, wildfly

First of all I would like to say, I´ve tried a read all threads here on SO and even on other pages which lead to zero success.

Here is my situation:
I have a docker-compose file where I have multiple container definitions. For example I have a 3 WildFly containers. For simplicity just say there is one container which I want to run (which is working perfectly, after docker-compose up I can see a entry WildFly page).

In docker compose I have exposed there ports
"8081:8080" - so on localhost:8081 I can see the welcome page
"8787:8787" - this should be debug port for wildFly (I plan to use different local ports and bind them to corresponding wildfly containers to their 8787 debug port).

All WildFly containers are run with --debug option (standalone.sh --debug ....)

When I start up the compose, I can see that 8787 port is in use, which means its binded as it should.

But When I try to add a new remote configuration with these options:

- debugger mode: Attach to remote JVM
- host: localhost
- port: 8787
  And then I try to run this configuration, I gen an error: **Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8787): java.io.IOEception "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"**

If I try to change the configuration to JDK 9+, the window in IDEA stays at JDK 5 - 8 (it wold persist). And as I am using the WildFly 21, which should be based on JDK greater than 9, that could be the problem but I do not know what to do with it to make it work.

After I find out which is the problem with one instance, I believe I will be able to run debug on all WildFly instances via other ports binded to containers 8787 port for each instance.

Thanks

E: I´ve tried even to go step by step using this Intellij tutorial https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-and-debug-a-spring-boot-application-using-docker-compose.html but I had no success. I´ve got the same same "handshake failed" error.

Comment: Looks like known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173607. Please checked if it fails with command line debugger as well: jdb -attach 8787.

Comment: @y.bedrov I am able to run jdb -attach 8787 command. (So no errors) but I do not know how to test if debugger is working properly

Comment: @y.bedrov I´ve editted my post with my second try to get remote debug working

Comment: So, it seems to be a bug in IDEA. Please follow mentioned ticket for updates.